# How to determine what Certificate Authorities to keep on my computer?

Tags: certificate-authority, certificate-revocation

I read [this article at Electronic Frontier Foundation](https://www.eff.org/deeplinks/2022/03/you-should-not-trust-russias-new-trusted-root-ca) on how Russian government wants the residents there to install a specific "Trusted Root CA" certificate. According to the article, this certificate has can inspect the users traffic.

It made me think about the various trusted root CAs that are currently installed on my machines, and I found information, such as [this article](https://www.altaro.com/hyper-v/view-revoke-manually-approve-certificates/), on how to view, revoke, and approve CAs on a Windows PC.

But based on what principles could you determine which ones to consider for removal if you have to determine it on your own?

Comment: Trust in CA's are established by policies and practices they follow (CP/CPS). Generally, they are authorized by governments or private organizations. So, you have to analyze the CA's and then install them. However, Microsoft also provides the 
Certificate/CRL updates offline as well, known as CTL Microsoft Trusted Root Program Updates.

Answer (score 3):

According to [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_authority#Providers), a study of the Alexa top 10 million web sites done in November 2021 found that the issuing CA's of the certificates used to secure these sites breaks down as follows:

```
Rank  Issuer                          Usage
1     IdenTrust                       36.0%
2     DigiCert                        16.9%
3     Sectigo (Comodo Cybersecurity)  15.3%
4     Let's Encrypt                   11.1%
5     GoDaddy                         5.6%
```

As you can see, 84.9% of the top 10 million sites on the web are secured using certificates issued by just five CA's.

You might want to start by including just the root certificates for these CA's in your trust store.  Then, as you surf the web - when you come across a site whose certificate is issued by a CA other than one of these, you can selectively decide whether or not to include this CA's root certificate in your trust store on a case-by-case basis.

Answer (score -1):

You need to determine what certificates are required for your daily use like browsing websites or installing software. This is often a fraction of what is installed on the system. But it can also depend on where you live because many countries have a root CA used for government services which you maybe need to access or a country/company prefers to use certificates from a certain CA for their services. In the end it is manual work to figure out what you need.

Comment: The question is "how do you do that?" You've just reiterated the question's problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).